# Behavior Flow Report Analysis

Tags: google-analytics

I've been tasked with something at my job that I have no idea how to do. I've tried Googling, but I'm not sure what terminology to use.

We are currently without an Analytics specialist and I am trying to fill in for the time being.

We recently created a "Related Styles" feature on our eCommerce site that will point users to similar items, etc. Our boss wants to know how many sales are being generated from the related styles.

We are already tracking sales on each individual item. I can imaging that it is possible to setup event tracking on when a related style is clicked and an event on when it is added to a cart.

But, what would be the best way to link these things together in order to create a comprehensive report for the boss?

Any guidance or advice would be welcome. Maybe a helpful article or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list variable in Enhanced Ecommerce for this.
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce

Or you can create new Custom Dimension with product scope and add "Related Styles" value in this CD.
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets

And in the end, The Behavior Flow report heavy relies on full Enhanced Ecommerce implementation.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction!